# Select - Oracle JSON Object - Join

Tags: json, oracle

I have a requirement to select column values in Oracle in a JSON structure. Let me explain the requirement in detail
We have a table called "dept" that has the following rows

[image]

There is another table called "emp" that has the following rows

[image]

The output we need is as follows

```
{"Data": [{
 "dept": "Sports",
 "City": "LA",
 "employees": {
"profile":[
  {"name": "Ben John", "salary": "15000"},
  {"name": "Carlos Moya", "salary": "19000"}]
}},
{"dept": "Sales",
 "City": "Miami",
 "employees": {
"profile":[
  {"name": "George Taylor", "salary": "9000"},
  {"name": "Emma Thompson", "salary": "8500"}]
  }}
]
}
```

The SQL that I issued is as follows

```
select  json_object('dept' value b.deptname,
                'city' value b.deptcity,
                'employees' value json_object('employee name' value a.empname,
                                                    'employee salary' value a.salary)
                format json) as JSONRETURN
from emp a, dept b where
a.deptno=b.deptno
```

However, the result looks like the following and not what we expected.

[image]

Please note the parent data is repeated. What is the mistake I am making?

Thanks for the help

Bala

Comment: I have not used them before but I think you need some combination of json_object, json_array, json_objectagg, and/or json_arrayagg. I'm looking at the 12.2 manual: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-6C3441E8-4F02-4E95-969C-BBCA6BDBBD9A There may be better ways to do it.

Comment: What Oracle version? Different versions have different tools added to the JSON toolbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this. Note the multiple (nested) calls to `json_object` and `json_arrayagg`. Tested in Oracle 12.2; other versions may have other tools that can make the job easier.

```
select json_object(
         'Data' value
           json_arrayagg(
             json_object (
               'dept'      value deptname,
               'City'      value deptcity,
               'employees' value
                 json_object(
                   'profile' value
                     json_arrayagg(
                       json_object(
                         'name'   value empname,
                         'salary' value salary
                       ) order by empid  -- or as needed
                     )      
                 )
             ) order by deptno  -- or as needed
           )
       ) as jsonreturn
from   dept join emp using (deptno)
group  by deptno, deptname, deptcity
;
```